# SVG not rendered in Ionic 3

Tags: svg, ionic-framework

I am experiencing some troubles rendering SVG images on my Ionic app. I am using SVG files generated with Adobe Photoshop and which are rendered perfectly on my browser. However they do not appear in my application (it's not a problem of path - an image is found but nothing is displayed). I checked with a random SVG image found online and it appears perfectly well.

Here is the content of my SVG file. I am not sure what the problem can be here.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="66" height="95" viewBox="0 0 66 95">
  <metadata><?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="Adobe XMP Core 5.6-c138 79.159824, 2016/09/14-01:09:01        ">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>

<?xpacket end="w"?></metadata>
<image id="Objet_dynamique_vectoriel_copie_36" data-name="Objet dynamique vectoriel copie 36" width="66" height="95" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/>
</svg>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what `<?xpacket>` does in your SVG, as I've never seen it myself.

Why are you using SVG anyway? Your `<image` tag of your SVG suggests you're trying to draw a PNG picture. (`xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,`)

I would simply try to export this PNG picture and load the PNG instead.
If you want a scalable 'play icon', I'd suggest trying to redraw the SVG as a proper vector image instead. (Lines)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was using SVG in order to have a scalable icon, but I didn't notice that this one just loaded a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Ramon that your use case is that you are using SVG to "wrap around" a raster image (Base64 encoded) so easiest for this use case is to use normal img tag.

Now as for SVG - you need to share you actual Ionic 3 template code and how exactly you are trying to render it.

Most likely issue here is that SVG tags are not using svg pre-tags for Angular in your code and Angular struggles to understand it is svg: basically should be  instead of  etc